# Collapse key on FCM diagnostics page is wrong (my Android package name)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

With FCM, I am seeing a weird behavior on the FCM diagnostics page where the collapseKey is set to my Android app's package name when I have a Notification payload (along with the data payload) with e=0 set in it. Is FCM unable to use collapseKey when Notification payload with e=0 is set? 
Note that I have collapseKey and contentAvailable with both Notification and Body payloads.

Answer (score 1):

The correct name of the field for collapse key is collapse_key, not collapseKey.

When you have a notification payload in the message, the message is always collapsible, and FCM generates a default collapse key for you if it doesn't find collapse_key in your message.

Note that maximum 4 collapse keys are allowed, and the default collapse_key takes one of these 4 slots, so you have only 3 left. If you specify more than these 3 user-generated collapse key, the behaviour of FCM is unspecified, so the reason might be that you have more than 3 different collapse keys.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: Thanks. I think that the issue might be that the FCM dashboard just renders the package name when I use the **default** collapse_key.

Note that my code is in JAVA and hence the camel-case field names which then get translated in JSON to the right dashed-lowercase format.

Comment: The correct field name depends if you are using the legacy payload format (such as for sendToDevice) or the new one. Old formats uses `collapse_key` while the new uses `collapseKey`. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#which_should_i_use